# Pagination - How can I store and provide a non-numeric page identifier?

Tags: zapier

I am trying to add pagination to my Zapier trigger.

The API I am using for the trigger supports pagination, but not using a page number in the traditional sense (ie. page 1,2,3,...). Instead, the API response includes a key (ie. "q1w2e3r4") which should be passed as a parameter to the next request to get the next page of results.

From looking at the docs, I can use `{{bundle.meta.page}}` (which defaults to 0 unless otherwise set).

I am trying to set `{{bundle.meta.page}}` in the code editor, with an example shown below:

```
const options = {
  url: 'company_xyz.com/api/widgets',
  method: 'GET',
  ...,
  params: {
    ...,
    'pagination_key': bundle.meta.page,
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const json_response = response.json;

    widgets = json_response.widgets
    ...

    bundle.meta.page = json_response["next_pagination_key"]

    return widgets;
  });
```

The problem is that when Zapier tries to retrieve the next page,  `bundle.meta.page` will be `1` instead of the value of "next_pagination_key" from the result of the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

There are docs on cursor-based pagination [in the CLI docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/packages/cli/README.md#paging).

The relevant block is:

```js
const performWithAsync = async (z, bundle) => {
  let cursor;
  if (bundle.meta.page) {
    cursor = await z.cursor.get(); // string | null
  }

  const response = await z.request(
    'https://5ae7ad3547436a00143e104d.mockapi.io/api/recipes',
    {
      // if cursor is null, it's sent as an empty query
      //   param and should be ignored by the server
      params: { cursor: cursor }
    }
  );

  // we successfully got page 1, should store the cursor in case the user wants page 2
  await z.cursor.set(response.nextPage);

  return response.items;
};
```

This *should* work in the Zapier Visual Builder, but you might need to use the CLI instead. You can export your integration using the `zapier convert` CLI command ([docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/master/docs/cli.md#convert)).

Comment: I tried to use the strategy that you suggested. However, I run into the following error: Invalid cursor operation. `z.cursor` can only be used in `perform` methods of polling triggers and when `canPaginate` is `true`. This seems to be happening when the "z.cursor.get" or "z.cursor.set" is returned as a promise. Is this expected?